# Как запустить TeamCity на отдельном Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat, teamcity

**Дано:**

Есть VPS на Debian. На нём есть `Tomcat`, на коем крутятся несколько сервлетов.

**Задача:**

Запустить на этом же сервере `TeamCity` так, чтобы он работал одновременно с уже работающими сервлетами.

**Проблема:**

Одновременно запустить не удаётся. Если запустить `TeamCity` - не работают сервлеты. Если сервлеты работают - не работает `TeamCity`.

**Что пробовал:**

Ковырял два дня настройки, доки. Пробовал порты менять везде, читал доки, гуглил. Вроде, должно работать, если запустить `TeamCity` на отдельном инстансе `Tomcat`. Но доки не помогают понять как это сделать. Вроде, там надо сначала копировать папку с `Tomcat` и прописывать `CATALINA_BASE`. Но какие именно папки копировать - непонятно. То ли уже имеющегося `Tomcat` то ли того, что в `TeamCity` встроен (а я не уверен, что он туда встроен).

**Вопрос:**

Как же это сделать?

---

**UPD_0:**

Попробовал так - пока шёл запуск `TeamCity` сервлеты работали. Как только он загрузился - сервлеты умерли (процесс `Tomcat` на другом порту умер.)

Нужно указать папку Tomcat другую. Для этого можно поправить скрипт запуска Tomcat, который встроен в архив с TeamCity. Скрипт находится тут:

```
ПАПКА_ГДЕ_НАХОДИТСЯ_TEAMCITY/bin/catalina.sh
```

Там есть строки для определения папки с Tomcat

> # Only set CATALINA_HOME if not already set
>   [ -z "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=cd "$PRGDIR/.." >/dev/null; pwd
>
> # Copy CATALINA_BASE from CATALINA_HOME if not already set
>   [ -z "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE="$CATALINA_HOME"

Перед ними нужно указать конкретную папку для Tomcat. Она будет совпадать с ПАПКА_ГДЕ_НАХОДИТСЯ_TEAMCITY:

```
export CATALINA_HOME="ПАПКА_ГДЕ_НАХОДИТСЯ_TEAMCITY"
export CATALINA_BASE="ПАПКА_ГДЕ_НАХОДИТСЯ_TEAMCITY"
```

Также указал другие порты для этого `Tomcat`

После этого TeamCity будет запускаться одновременно с действующими сервлетами, которые крутятся другим экземпляром Tomcat.

Comment: можно еще отдельный war загрузить в уже существующий томкат